# Pitch shifting with USB audio interface

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, games, audio-sync

Sometimes with my Behringer UMC202HD interface, the pitch of some things will be shifted down. This often happens when I start a game - for example, starting X-Plane will *always* result in this happening, and the pitch of everything in the system will be shifted down. Skype sometimes also does this. Often I can fix the problem by simply unplugging the interface and then plugging it back in.

With other things, however, the problem is more subtle and not fixable in a reproducible way. With the Witcher 3, for example, the dialogue only (not the music!) is pitch shifted down. This is noticeable because the dialogue lines consistently get cut off suddenly before they end. I don't know what might cause this - I have VSync turned off, and a constant 60fps.

FWIW, I'm using Pulseaudio. I don't have any custom configurations set up as far as I'm aware. This is as really disconcerting problem that I've been struggling to find a solution for a for a while, so any help is very much appreciated.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but I also have this problem on my 18.04.3 laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`. Find the line that reads:

```
; default-sample-rate = 44100
```

and uncomment it by removing the `;`. Then, find the line just below that reads:

```
; alternate-sample-rate = 48000
```

and change it to:

```
alternate-sample-rate = 44100
```

Finally, restart pulse with `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start`.

This way pulse will always run at the same sample rate and you'll be able to avoid the weird pitch shifting.

I haven't yet encountered any negative effects from this solution.

Comment: Still have low pitch after doing this.

Comment: I had to change the sample-rate to 48000 on both of them in order for it to fix the low pitch